# google analytics - include filter nto working

Tags: filter, include, google-analytics

I just added an Include filter this morning in my domain (test.org). I have

Custom Filter > Include > Request URI > ^/test-a/46212$|^/test-a/46212|^/test-a/46315

Now after I go to Content > Site Content > All Pages, I see stats for other pages that I didnt include in my filter. For ex I see /somethingelse. I only want to see stats for /test-a/46212 and whatever else in my filter.

Please let me know what im doing wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you set the date filter when you looked at your reports ? Filters do not change historical data (if you want to filter historical data you should use custom segments).

Comment: Yes. I set the date to today since I created the profile today with the corresponding filter. I've created filters like this in the past and I've never had any issues.

Comment: Filters can take 24 hours to be applied. Try tomorrow.

Comment: I ended up changing my filter. I also added it to my existent filter. I"m honestly not sure if that will affect my current stats. But now it's showing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've probably already moved on, but I was struggling with behavior similar to what you were seeing for some time (where google didn't seemed to pay attention to changes in my filters).

From my testing, it appears that changes to pre-defined filters seem to take effect quickly (immediately), but changes to *custom* filters can take "a couple of hours" according to google's site (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en). I'm not sure exactly how long "a couple of hours is".  For one of my filters, I set it yesterday afternoon, and it was finally working this morning.  For another profile, I changed the filter about 20 hours ago, and that profile still isn't showing what the filter indicates it should be.

The delay makes it a pain to debug filters since, when there is a problem, you can't know for sure if your filter is wrong, or if google just hasn't applied it yet (or if there is a bug on google's side for a particular filter)...

Anyway, I hope that's helpful to someone else that may be struggling with google-analytics filters.